# present 128-bit long data

Tags: c, unions, largenumber

I need to represent a 128-bit unsigned integer and pass it to API having a prototype `int lib_api(unsigned char *data, size_t len)`. I have the following in mind:

```
union {
  unsigned char u8[16];
  uint16_t u16[8];
  uint32_t u32[4];
};
```

or

```
struct {
  uint64_t hi;
  uint64_t lo;
};
```

What option would be easier to use and implement? I know there's gcc specific 128bit types, but I would like to have more portable implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue with both options is endianness.

If you know the endianness of the platform, you can implement it whichever way you like. Be aware that the code you write is thus non-portable, so you should take the corresponding precautions to ensure that it is running in a platform with the correct endianness.

Another pitfall concerns the size of `unsigned char`. For the most part, this is 8 bits just about everywhere. But it is not *required* to be, and this is something that can cause problems. However, since this code is probably for a specific platform, you can easily check that.

The end result is that you have two possible solutions. The most portable solution you'll find looks like this:

```
struct int128 {
  unsigned char values[16];
};
```

...but the most practical solution tends to look like this:

```
union int128 {
  unsigned char u8[16];
  uint16_t u16[8];
  uint32_t u32[4];
  uint64_t u64[2];
  struct {
    // anonymous struct, also assuming big-endian given your example
    uint64_t hi;
    uint64_t lo;
  };
};
```

Whichever one you will want to use will depend on your specific project.

EDIT: if you have gcc-specific 128-bit types available, you can always add them to the union too, protected by an `#ifdef __GNUC__`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What benefit does putting "unsigned char values[16]" in a structure give?

Comment: @Mark Arrays are passed by reference, structures are passed by value. If the type represents an integer, you'd often need to pass it around _by value_ — using a struct gives you this possibility (while you can still pass the pointer around easily).